# Input property binding issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I am experimenting with Angular 8 and passing data between components.

The child component is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectService } from '../select.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dynamic-selects, test-dynamic-tag',
      templateUrl: './dynamic-selects.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dynamic-selects.component.css']
    })
    export class DynamicSelectComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() id: any;
      options: any[];
      constructor(private selector: SelectService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
        console.log("TESTING INPUT VALUE: " + this.id);
        console.log(this.id);

        this.selector.users().subscribe(users => {
          this.options = users;
        });
      }
    }
```

The parent template is where the problem is being manifested.
I am attempting to output different examples of the child component tag but only the component tags where *[id]* is an integer are being output. Tags with strings just say 'undefined'.

*@Input() id* is typed as **any** but even typing is as **string** does not resolve the issue.

Below is the parent component markup:

```html
<app-dynamic-selects [id]="7"></app-dynamic-selects>
<br><br>
<test-dynamic-tag [id]="test"></test-dynamic-tag>
<br><br>
<app-dynamic-selects [id]="Batman"></app-dynamic-selects>
<br><br>
<test-dynamic-tag [id]="14"></test-dynamic-tag>
```

As shown above, I am using 2 different selector tags for the same component. But it doesn't matter which I use, subsequent tags print out **undefined**.

Here is what is printed in my console area from the html above:

*TESTING INPUT VALUE: 7


7


TESTING INPUT VALUE: undefined


undefined


TESTING INPUT VALUE: undefined


undefined


TESTING INPUT VALUE: 14


14*

Why do I get undefined rather than the output, string or integer, that I expect?

Comment: The parent and child components look the same except for the subscription part . Besides even the selectors and tags don't match. Are you sure you posted the correct question? Review it again .

Comment: @MohitSingh: Apologies. I was fighting sleep in the early hours of the morning when I posted. I have provided clarifications to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using bracket syntax, you are binding to a expression, typically a property in your component. A number literal is a valid expression, so the binding works. `test` and `Batman` is not a valid expression if there's no property of that name defined in your component. `'test'` and `'Batman'` would work, since a string literal is a valid expression.

When binding to literals, you don't really need the bracket syntax though, simply use the normal html attribute syntax (i.e. without brackets).

Answer (score 1):

to complete the response of Markus Dresch, you can use either

```
<test-dynamic-tag [id]="test"></test-dynamic-tag>
```

and then you should have a variable named `test` in you rcontroller

or

```
<test-dynamic-tag id="test"></test-dynamic-tag>
```

and then you pass a String value to your child component